# Create static instance of struct in C without knowing struct implementation

Tags: c, static, malloc

I have the following header file:

```
typedef struct my_data my_data_t;
my_data_t* new_my_data(void);
void free_my_data(my_data_t* my_data);
```

And the corresponding c file:

```
typedef struct my_data
{
  int val;
} my_data_t;

my_data_t* new_my_data()
{
  my_data_t* ptr = (my_data_t*)malloc(sizeof(my_data_t));
  return ptr;
}

void free_my_data(my_data_t* my_data)
{
  free(my_data);
}
```

I would like to create in instance of my_data_t in static memory without using malloc. I'd like to do this by adding the following to the header file:

```
int sizeof_my_data(void);
```

...and this to the c file:

```
int sizeof_my_data()
{
  return sizeof(my_data_t);
}
```

...and doing something like this:

```
static my_data_t* my_data_instance = static_alloc(sizeof_my_data());
```

Is this possible? **I'd like to do this because the target machine for this code is a microprocessor that doesn't handle malloc (in our case, it's best that all structures be held in static memory), and I'd like to keep the actual data structure of my_data hidden from the code that implements it.** Any other suggestions on how to accomplish the goal are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding to your header file

```
my_data_t *get_static_data();
```

and to your c file

```
my_data_t *get_static_data()
{
    static my_data_t static_my_data;
    return &static_my_data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The usual way of doing this is to create an opaque struct in your header file with the correct size.  For example:

```
#define MY_DATA_SIZE 32
struct my_data_t
{
    char opaque_data[MY_DATA_SIZE];
};
```

This is how the various pthreads data types (such as `pthread_mutex_t`) are defined.

Comment: Note that this technique may run into alignment issues, since `char` requires only byte-alignment, but more complex structures typically have stronger alignment requirements.

Comment: Excellent point, Raymond.  Now that I take a closer look, the pthreads types are defined as a union of a `char` array of the appropriate size and another type that provides the required alignment (such as `long int`).